# Insert Row in Dataframe at certain place

Tags: python, dataframe, insert, row

I have the following Dataframe:
[image: Dataframe]

Now i want to insert an empty row **after** every time the column "Zweck" equals 7.
So for example the third row should be an empty row.

Comment: please replace the image with reproducible data (we can't copy/paste an image to run the data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'f': [1, 7, 3, 4, 7]})
ren_dict = {i: df.columns[i] for i in range(len(df.columns))}

ind = df[df['f'] == 7].index
df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, ind, values=[33], axis=0))
df.rename(columns=ren_dict, inplace=True)

ind_empt = df['a'] == 33
df[ind_empt] = ''

print(df)
```

Output

```
   a  b  f
0  1  1  1
1         
2  2  2  7
3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4
5         
6  5  5  7
```

Here the dataframe is overwritten, as the append operation will be resource intensive. As a result, the required strings with values 33 appear. This is necessary because `np.insert` does not allow `string` values to be substituted. Columns are renamed to their original state with: `df.rename`. Finally, we find lines with `df['a'] == 33` to set to empty values.

Comment: But this deletes the rowwith the value 7? I don't want to delete the row.

Comment: I thought that you need lines instead of these lines, but empty ones. That is, you need to exclude these strings altogether?

Comment: I want to have an empty row after a row with the value 7.

Comment: Updated solution with description.